# How can I add a foreword or a preface before the TOC in a (pdflatex) sphinx document?

Tags: python-sphinx, pdflatex, tableofcontents

How can I use [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org) to generate a `pdflatex` document in which there is some text *before* the table of contents? The generated LaTeX file always seems to have `\tableofcontents` before any document-body text.

I have been unable to find any information / documentation on this, and I'd appreciate it if anyone has any tips. I am not interested in 'manual' solutions which require modifying the tex file directly -- I am looking for directives / options which can be specified directly within rst files.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a value for `latex_elements['preamble']` in your `conf.py` file.

Comment: Can you give more details how to set preamble in `rst` file?